# Redirect subdomain to internal IP

Tags: dns, domain, redirection, nat

I have a Fortigate 80C at home and have a number of servers hosted: mail, git, web, RDP, voip etc.

Now I want these subdomains to redirect to certain internal IPs:

```
mail.domain.com > 192.168.0.200
git.domain.com > 192.168.0.201
www.domain.com > 192.168.0.202
rdp.domain.com > 192.168.0.203
voip.domain.com > 192.168.0.204
```

Now I have one external IP (X.Y.Z.20), so I was wondering is it possible for the Fortigate box to to pick up what subdomain has referred the client to its external IP (X.Y.Z.20) and then deal with the traffic accordingly?

Ideally I would like to `ssh` in to mail, git and www to administer them without having to use random port numbers, I would like to be able to execute ssh like so:

`ssh administrator@mail.domain.com`, `ssh administrator@git.domain.com`, etc

Without having to specify a specific port.

I know I could set up NAT rules to redirect say port `12345` on `X.Y.Z.20` to port `22` on `192.168.0.200` but would much rather just have the router utilise the FQDN to do a direct NAT from every port on the FQDN to every port on the internal box.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!
Myles

Comment: Hi Chris, webmail isn't such a problem as I can create a VirtualHost in Apache for specific subdomains/directories. The main problem here I suppose is ssh'ing in to the separate *nix servers without using random ports...

Say if I could get extra external IPs I would be able to do the above couldn't I?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to reverse proxy SSH. So you'd have to get more external IPs, use different ports, or use one as a bridgehead for SSHing into the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is generically called 'reverse proxy', a quick Google suggests the 80C doesn't support it.

Some of the ports can probably be forwarded separately, the RDP on port 3389 and SIP has it's own ports too. SMTP is on port 25, but if you want webmail then it will coincide with the www server. Git typically runs on 9418, so it should be good too.

I'm not aware of any way to reverse proxy SSH. So you'd have to get more external IPs, use different ports, or use one as a bridgehead for SSHing into the others.

Answer (score 0):

afaik not possible like you want to use it in this setup. sorry :-(

you could use a proxy-style-setup (need a proxy for every used service) or your nat/port solution

Comment: thx for downvote... accepted answer says the same but more in detail. this makes people who try to help real happy.

Comment: For the record I didn't downvote...

Comment: ok, sorry for my offense.

Comment: @Michael, it doesn't matter how good your answers are, you'll eventually get a drive by downvote for no apparent reason. Or my personal favorite, someone disagrees with one little point in your much larger answer and downvotes you for that. It happens, if you stick around it'll happen again, it's just a part of life around SE. BTW: Long and detailed answers tend to get more upvotes and the accept.